# setup two Raspberry Pi 4s to communicate to each other through AdHoc

Tags: pi-4

I am working on a project where there is a need for two Raspberry Pi 4s to communicate to each other though AdHoc connection. I managed to set up AdHoc on both Pis but I couldn't make them to talk to each other. Any help please. 
The configuration I made is as follows:

1. from etc/network, I edited the *interfaces* file like this:
        auto wlan0
        iface wlan0 inetstatic
         address 192.168.4.1
         netmask 255.255.255.0
         wireless-channel 1
         wireless-essid MyAdhoc
          wireless-mode ad-hoc
2. I installed isc-dhcp-server
3. from etc/default i edited isc-dhcp-server to include lik the following:
      INTERFACESv4="wlan0"
4. from etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf I edited like the following:

   option domain-name "example.org";

   option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;

   authoritative;

   subnet 192.168.4.0 netmask 255.255.255.0;

   range 192.168.4.150 192.168.4.170;

   option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;

   option domain-name "example.org";

   option routers 192.168.4.1;

   option broadcast-address 192.168.4.255;

   default-lease-time 600;

   max-lease-time 7200;

This configuration successfully created AdHoc on raspberry pis but it doesn't help to talk to each other

Comment: How do you think we could help you without knowing anything about your configurations? It's like I would asked you: "I build a helicopter, it looks like a helicopter and has a rotor but it doesn't fly. Why?"

Comment: Ah, let me see.  B43 does not like Rpi4B buster. Perhaps you can try Arch. References: (1) Ad-hoc networking - ArchWiki
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ad-hoc_networking

(2) B43 - Linux Wireless Wiki
https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/b43

Comment: Having 2 DHCP servers on a network won't work - indeed having 1 on an Adhoc is meaningless

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer. Thank you so much. I am still trying to follow your way.

Comment: @Milliways. How does the AdHoc assign IPs with out the DHCP?

Comment: A [wireless ad hoc network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_ad_hoc_network) is a generic term for direct connections without a router but doesn't specify a technical solution. Any device, incl. Raspberry Pis, following the IEEE 802.11 standard have to present [ad hoc connections with IBSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_set_(802.11_network)#Service_set_ID_(SSID)). Do you configure **IBSS** for your ad hoc network?