# Raspberry pi connection

Tags: pi-3

I am trying to connect two pis together wireless.

I made both pis an access point does that affect them must one of them be a simple pi with the configurations listed or can both be AP and connect to each other?

Comment: Only one should be an access point.

Comment: You are thinking about an *ad hoc* network.  I've never done this, so I won't try to answer your question, but a little searching found this: [P2P ad-hoc WIFI does works but it ain't simple](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=91969)  Do note that it is from 2014 and involves wireless USB dongles; things might be simpler now.

Comment: Also, there is a very similar question here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/108828/85029

Answer (score 1):

In the wireless world you need AP and STA.

AP is an access points to which STA (Station = clients) can connect.

So one Raspberry Pi needs to be AP and the other needs to be STN.